# Which is the best method to push dataframe into sql server?

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory

I am very new to Azure, I need to know what is the best method to push my pandas dataframe of around 10gb into sql server and what services are better to handle 10-13 gb of data. Currently I am using Python Azure func, where I do some Etl and finally the clean Data of 10 gb needs to be pushed to sql server?

I am confused with the following points

1. Is Azure Databricks is better than Azure function in terms of time and cost, to process 10GB-15GB Data?
2. For pushing data, what is the better method:
   Pushing from python by using: `df.to_sql('products', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)` or Using ADF Copy activity? -- Any other suggestions are welcome.
3. Should I choose PySpark over Python in Azure data brick, In order to have faster process?

Comment: If you use Databricks, you should also use PySpark instead of pandas as PySpark uses the cluster nodes for processing which pandas, as far as I know, does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the comments have mentioned, it is faster to load data to SQL using Pyspark.

Code to load the pyspark dataframe to SQL

```
from datetime import datetime
servername = "jdbc:sqlserver://mytestserver.database.windows.net:1433"
dbname = "mydbname"
url = servername + ";" + "databaseName=" + dbname + ";"
dbtable = "Mytable"
user = "xxxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" # Please specify password here
 
def writeToSQL(df_raw):
# Adding an id column with unique values
    uuidUdf= udf(lambda : str(uuid.uuid4()),StringType())
    nowUdf= udf(lambda : int(time.time() * 1000),LongType())
    df_raw = df1 \
      .withColumn("id", uuidUdf()) \
      .withColumn("insertedAt", nowUdf()) \
 
    try:
        df_raw.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", dbtable) \
        .option("user", user) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .save()
    except ValueError as error :
        print("Connector write failed", error)

df_raw=spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF)  #convert pandas to pyspark
starttime = datetime.utcnow()
print("Starting ingestion: ", datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
writeToSQL(df_raw)
endtime = datetime.utcnow()
print("Finished ingestion: ", datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
print("Time taken :" + str(endtime-starttime))
```

Comment: At this line df_raw=spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF)  #convert pandas to pyspark... You are converting pandas dataframe to Pyspark and then pushing the data to SQL. My question is, you ran all your etl in Python and at the time of pushing you just converted pandas df to pyspark df ?

Comment: Well yes. A python dataframe does not offer the performance pyspark does. Ofcourse you can load the pandas dataframe directly(using different code) but that is going to take ages. To load the data to SQL using pyspark, you need a pyspark dataframe. You said you are using Python currently but your question was which is faster. Pyspark is a clear winner here with regards to performance and using Python on databricks is a bit of a waste when Databricks offers spark. If possible you should change your current ETL to Pyspark.